# How to locate module_init() offset from ELF header of Linux kernel module?

Tags: disassembly, linux, elf, driver, entry-point

The header is self explanatory but to explain myself better.
I have an ELF binary - loadable kernel module, compiled with symbols.
I want to know how to locate the offset of the `module_init()` function.
Can I find this info using *`readelf`* ?

Comment: For example, https://lwn.net/Articles/531148/ Also, module_init is not a real function, it's a macro as described in that article.

Comment: @TakashiYamamoto: Tell me if I am wrong, but I always thought that the `init_module()` function was located at the start of the module address... Have you examples where it is not the case? I am interested to know about!

Answer (score 2):

To read with *readelf* the parameter is "-s":

```
 Options are:
    -a --all               Equivalent to: -h -l -S -s -r -d -V -A -I
    -h --file-header       Display the ELF file header
    -l --program-headers   Display the program headers
        --segments          An alias for --program-headers
    -S --section-headers   Display the sections' header
       --sections          An alias for --section-headers
    -g --section-groups    Display the section groups
    -t --section-details   Display the section details
    -e --headers           Equivalent to: -h -l -S
    -s --syms              Display the symbol table
       --symbols           An alias for --syms
    --dyn-syms             Display the dynamic symbol table
    -n --notes             Display the core notes (if present)
```

So, with *readelf -s module.ko* is enough to read the symbols.

Answer (score -3):

First disassemble your module

```
objdump -xDsl module.ko > disassemble.txt
```

Then edit the file and search for section init. It look like this:

Disassembly of section `.init.text`:

```
002bdb01 <init_module>:
init_fct():
```

Comment: This answer looks like it has great potential for improvement. @laurent can I suggest you edit it to elaborate a bit more?